# Visual studio 2022- incompatible installer project or doesn't support specific csproj file

Tags: windows-installer, csproj, visual-studio-setup-proje

Recently I moved our Visual Studio 2019 project to VS 2022 but faced errors like incompitable project (Unsupported

This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them...)

Problem Resolved:

After some R&D I found Visual Studio 2022 doesn't come with the Setup Project extension so, need to add another extension as given below

Extension>Manage Extensions>Online search and install "Microsoft Visual Studio Projects 2022" >restart the VS>reload the incompatible installer project

Problem resolved successfully

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved:

After some R&D I found Visual Studio 2022 doesn't come with the "Setup Project" extension so, need to add another extension as given below

Extension>Manage Extensions>Online search and install "Microsoft Visual Studio Projects 2022" >restart the VS>reload the incompatible installer project

Problem resolved successfully